# Angular, Failed to set the 'responseType' property on 'XMLHttpRequest'

Tags: angular, asynchronous, httprequest

in dev mode, everything works fine but after building and deploying the app I'm getting this error when using `HttpClient`

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'responseType' property on 'XMLHttpRequest': The response type cannot be changed for synchronous requests made from a document
```

in the build version, all the `XMLHttpRequest` are using sync mode.

I updated manually the main.ts to add a third parameter 'true' to this function `r.open(e.method,e.urlWithParams)` to force async mode and now it works fine.

but I have to do that for every new build and I don't think that it is the better way to solve that issue.

here is my service

```
  private headers = new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "dataType": "json",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Expires": "0"
  });

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  updateConfig(property: string, value: string): Observable<any> {
    var json_data = {
      ...
    };

    return this.http.post<any>(
      "url",
      json_data,
      { headers: this.headers }
    );
  }
```

and how I subscribe to it

```
  setPlatform(platform: any): void {
    this.sub = this.mfdAPIService.updateConfig("platform", platform)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.router.navigate(["/configuration"]);
      });
  }

Angular CLI: 13.3.7
Node: 16.15.0
Package Manager: npm 8.5.5
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.3.10
animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.7
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.7
@angular/cli                    13.3.7
@schematics/angular             13.3.7
rxjs                            7.5.5
typescript                      4.6.4

ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'responseType' property on 'XMLHttpRequest': The response type cannot be changed for synchronous requests made from a document.
    at n._subscribe (http://10.12.27.7/aplpx/client/77eba8ab-826a-4f36-bb69-048b58feb376/main.43ef631b6c4e0013.js:1:255555)
    at n._trySubscribe (http://10.12.27.7/aplpx/client/77eba8ab-826a-4f36-bb69-048b58feb376/main.43ef631b6c4e0013.js:1:4909)
    at http://10.12.27.7/aplpx/client/77eba8ab-826a-4f36-bb69-048b58feb376/main.43ef631b6c4e0013.js:1:4854
    at Aa (http://10.12.27.7/aplpx/client/77eba8ab-826a-4f36-bb69-048b58feb376/main.43ef631b6c4e0013.js:1:2628)
    at n.subscribe (http://10.12.27.7/aplpx/client/77eba8ab-826a-4f36-bb69-048b58feb376/main.43ef631b6c4e0013.js:1:4768)
    at p (http://10.12.27.7/aplpx/client/77eba8ab-826a-4f36-bb69-048b58feb376/main.43ef631b6c4e0013.js:1:12547)
    at h (http://10.12.27.7/aplpx/client/77eba8ab-826a-4f36-bb69-048b58feb376/main.43ef631b6c4e0013.js:1:12487)
    at AT._next (http://10.12.27.7/aplpx/client/77eba8ab-826a-4f36-bb69-048b58feb376/main.43ef631b6c4e0013.js:1:8022)
    at AT.next (http://10.12.27.7/aplpx/client/77eba8ab-826a-4f36-bb69-048b58feb376/main.43ef631b6c4e0013.js:1:2877)
    at n._subscribe (http://10.12.27.7/aplpx/client/77eba8ab-826a-4f36-bb69-048b58feb376/main.43ef631b6c4e0013.js:1:11124)
```

when I run ng update

```
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 30 dependencies.
    We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

      Name                               Version                  Command to update
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular/cli                       13.3.7 -> 14.0.1         ng update @angular/cli
      @angular/core                      13.3.10 -> 14.0.1        ng update @angular/core

    There might be additional packages which don't provide 'ng update' capabilities that are outdated.
    You can update the additional packages by running the update command of your package manager.
```

Comment: Check the networks tab, is the request completed successfully? Do you see response getting back from server?

Comment: nothing in the network tab, since the error happens while preparing the XMLHttpRequest. so the call is not triggered.

question updated with the full console log

Comment: Try to make an "ng update" and copy/paste the instructions provided.